# Can I put an ObjectiveC @selector in a NSDictionary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dynamic, nsdictionary, selector

```
[actionMap setObject:@selector(actionNavPop) forKey:@"navPop"];
```

This doesn't work.  `NSDictionary` can only hold objects, and a `SEL` type is not an object.

For number types you can do `[NSNumber numberWithInt:123]` but is there any sort of similar object wrapper for selectors?

Comment: A `SEL` *is* a pointer (of type `objc_selector *`), incidentally.

Comment: I stand corrected.  But it's still not an "object" so NSDictionary doesn't like it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use `NSStringFromSelector()` and `NSSelectorFromString()`.